# Split sequence of numbers from 1 to n^2 in n subsequences so they all have the same sum

Tags: algorithm

Given the number n and a sequence of numbers from 1 to n^2 how to split it in n subsequences so all of the subsequences have the same sum and length of n ?

For example if n = 3 answer could be:

> 3 4 8 = 15
>
> 2 6 7 = 15
>
> 1 5 9 = 15

Comment: Can you provide an example input and output ?

Comment: @zenwraight edited

Comment: And now provide your code attempts and explain what was wrong with them.

Comment: There's a simple formula for getting the sum of all numbers from 1 to `x`: `(x)*(x+1)/2`. In your case, `x=n^2` and you need to divide that total into `n` equal parts, so each sum will need to be `n*(n^2+1)/2`.

Comment: I have added an answer for the above post, it will work for any n >= 1. Let me know if you find anything wrong in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I feel this problem can be solved by making few observations to the problem.

For example, let's say we have `n=3`. Then `n^2=9`.

Now total sum of all the numbers from `1 to 9` = `9 * (9+1) / 2` = `45`.

So, now we can split 45 into three equal groups each having `sum = 45/3 = 5`.

Similarly:-

```
n = 4, sum of 1 to 16 numbers = 16 * 17/2 = 136. each group sum = 136/4 = 34.
n = 5, sum of 1 to 25 numbers = 25 * 26/2 = 25*13. each group sum = 25*13/5 = 65.
```

Now, we know what should be sum of each set of groups in order to split numbers into n sub sequences.

Now Another observation that we make is whether our n is `odd` or `even`.

For n being even, the splitting it very easy.

```
n = 2, so we have numbers 1 to 4. 
1 4
2 3.
```

Let's assume a matrix of n x n , in above case it will be 2 x 2.

```
Rules for even n:-
1. Keep a counter = 1.
2. Fill the first column (1 to n), incrementing the counter by 1.
3. When we reach at the bottom of the column, for column 2, we do a reverse iteration (n to 1) and fill them with counter by incrementing it by 1.
```

You can verify this technique will work by taking n=2,4,6 ... and filling the array.

Now let's see how to fill this matrix n x n for n odd.

```
Rules for odd n:-
1. Keep a counter = 1.
2. Fill the first column (1 to n), incrementing the counter by 1.
3. Now this case is slightly different from even case, from the next column onwards, 
 we don't reverse our calculation from n to 1 but we keep moving ahead in column. 
 Let's understand this step by looking at an example.
```

Let's take n=3.

Our first column will be 1,2,3.

Now for the second column we start at bottom column which is n in our example it's 3.

Fill the `n = 3` with value `4`. next row value = `(n+1)%n = 0`, which gets `5`, next row = `(n+1+1)%n = 1` , which gets value `6`. Now all the column `2` values are filled, let's move onto next column i.e third.

We will start at row = 1 , so row 1 column 3 will get 7, then row 2 column 3 will get 8 and then row 0 column 3 will get 9.

Hope this helps!